# automatically refresh ads on website

Tags: javascript

I am using sovrn ad network at my website, here are a few script lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ap.lijit.com/www/delivery/fpi.js?z=1&u=abc&width=300&height=600"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ap.lijit.com/www/delivery/fpi.js?z=2&u=abc&width=300&height=250"></script>
```

I would like to refresh every ad position each 20 seconds. Any idea how to refresh just ad positions withou refreshing whole page?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a page that only has the ad on it, you can add it as a frame to your page and refresh the frame.

Refresh the frame:

```
document.getElementById('ad1').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Add this to your page:

```
<iframe id="ad1" src="*your ad page*" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Make sure to set the width and your height to the size of your ad.

Comment: One more question - if in my question is ad starting with "<script" tag, is is good enough to use your  "<iframe" tag?  I mean if ads will be working good, so if it is not necessary to use "<script" tag (?) Thanks.

Comment: You put the script tag on the extra page with the ad and use the iframe to link to that page.